# Control gets transferred to servlet during file upload from html page

Tags: java, javascript, html, ajax, servlets

i am trying to use file upload functionality in my application.i am using the following code in my html

```
<form action="http://localhost:8080/demo/Upload/a" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" name="description" />
<input type="file" name="file" />
<input type="submit" />
```

on clicking the submit button the URL of the servlet appears in the address bar of my browser.However i do not want this.I want the same page to appear on my screen after clicking on submit..something like ajax where the page does not get reloaded after posting data.How can i achieve this?

Comment: That's it you have got the right answer yourself. Use `AJAX` and you are done

Comment: can you provide me with some sample code that i can use for calling my servlet?

Comment: Google for fileupload using AJAX. Stackoverflow will help if you have already tried something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually file uploads are not possible using pure AJAX because JavaScript doesn't have direct access to filesystem. However there are certain ways of doing it using iframes. So there is a [jQuery plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) to handle all this stuff for you.